# Use period as thousands separator in number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a number `var test_price = 94600`. I want to multiply it by the value a user types in an `<input name="quantity" />` element, and to show that result in a `<p id="sample">` element. This is self-describing: in the `<p>` element it shows the total price (`price * quantity`). I've managed to do that:

```
$('input[name="quantity"]').change(function () {
    var test_price = 94600;
    var quantity = $('input[name="quantity"]').val();
    var price_without_thousands_separator = $('#sample').html(test_price * quantity);
});
```

[**As you can see it's working**](https://jsfiddle.net/0wg7y6x9/).

Now I just want to add a period (.) after every three units to the `#sample` paragraph. So if you have 1 as quantity it will show 94.600, if you have quantity=3 then 283.800, if quantity=8 then 756.800 and so on. Yes I know the usual tradition is to use commas, but here in my country we're used to read periods as thousands separators and commas as decimals (*e.g.* for us π = 3.14, **not** 3,14).

Happy holidays!!

Comment: The above is a duplicate in that all you have to do is switch `","` to `"."` in the code it gives.

Comment: How can I insert his code (`function numberWithCommas(x) {return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");}`) into mine? I don't undestand that

Comment: You have to add this function and call it when setting the html                       var price_without_thousands_separator = $('#sample').html(numberWithCommas(test_price * quantity));

Comment: Hey @bormat thank you a lot! There're some things I still don't understand very well such as parameters/arguments in JS. If any body wants to test the new code, **[here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/0wg7y6x9/4/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a very simple solution for up to 6 digits.

```
var x = test_price * quantity;
x = x.toString();
var withComma = x.slice(0, x.length - 3) + ',' + x.slice(-3);
```

to make this more robust, you may want to make a formatInt() function that loops through your string and at every 3rd digit from the end adds the comma

Comment: How would I use that `formatInt()`? [You can see you solution worked](http://jsfiddle.net/0wg7y6x9/3), but once the value of input is greater than or equal to 11, the number is displayed 1040.600 instead of 1.400.600.

Comment: I'd go with this regex solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/3465999

so in your case, add that function and call

    numberWithCommas(test_price * quantity). Also, replace the ',' with '.'